# How should one deal with "The following package disappeared from your system..."?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, dpkg

On dpkg-/apt-based systems, it is possible to encounter a message such as the following:

```
The following package disappeared from your system as
all files have been overwritten by other packages:
  qfdevelopment_metapkg
Note: This is done automatically and on purpose by dpkg.
```

What does this even mean?  How should we deal with it?

In this case, qfdevelopment_metapkg is an apt package that contains only dependencies in order to install the necessary packages prior to performing development for the qf project.  I had installed the package (originally) using:

```
sudo dpkg -i qfdevelopment_metapkg-0.3.8-Linux.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

I am eager to know how others deal with this, since I don't understand the workaround that I fumbled through (which I'll list if it does not come up in answers).

Answer (score 2):

Why we should care: this issue manifests when a `sudo apt-get upgrade` helpfully offers that autoremove will remove all of the just added packages - because the package that depends on them was removed.

**Workaround**

It seems that this results from the package not installing anything.  I solved the problem by adding a trivial script that I install into the bin directory:

```
INSTALL(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/list_qf_dev_info DESTINATION bin)
```

The contents of this list_qf_dev_info script are just:

```
#! /bin/sh

apt-cache show qfdevelopment_metapkg
```

Now, after installing, the presence of this script causes the apt/deb system to keep the package instead of automatically causing it to disappear.

**Alternate workaround - without editing deb**

A different workaround - that does not require modifying the deb - is to just install again at the end to get things squared away:

```
sudo dpkg -i qfdevelopment_metapkg-0.3.8-Linux.deb
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg -i qfdevelopment_metapkg-0.3.8-Linux.deb
```

**PS**

I had forgotten about this issue as I had worked unrelated items.  Today I was running into the issue again and was briefly excited to see somebody had asked before realizing it's my question and that there were no answers, so I had to fumble through it myself.